# INPUT FILE VALIDAT DATA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I cannot seem to figure out a problem. here is what I'm trying to do open and read the content of a .txt file.   If there is a problem with one of the lines of data in the file skip it and continue reading the file

I cannot find a method to skip the line that does not contain a valid value and continue to read the file. Here is my code.

```
int theValue = 0;

try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String value = input.next();

            theValue = Integer.parseInt(value);



        }
        input.close();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException error) {
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: please provide all of the code you are using not just a section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe not the best idea, but a simple solution would be to encapsulate parseInt in a try/catch:

```
int theValue = 0;

try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String value = input.next();

            try{
                theValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Just ignore it and carry on.
            }



        }
        input.close();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException error) {
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }
}
```